# radio buttons setting account type in mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

hey guys need to pick your brains, i currently have a form set up that uses 6 radio buttons which do 2 things.

a, is supposed to set my account field in mysqli which uses a enym field with the values of a,b,c ect

b, shows a div that includes my resgistration form showing the fields i need based on the account.

the problem i have faced is getting the the data into mysqli of which radio button is selected or "checked". all the other fileds in the form post into mysql fine its just getting the radio button to post its value.

ok php is as follows

```
    <?php

$errorMsg = "";
// First we check to see if the form has been submitted 
if (isset($_POST['firstname'])){
    //Connect to the database through our include 
    include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
    // Filter the posted variables
    $username = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['username']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $firstname = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z]", "", $_POST['firstname']); // filter everything but letters
    $surname = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z]", "", $_POST['surname']); // filter everything but letters
    $accounttype = preg_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['accounttype']); // filter everything but lowercase letters
    $b_m = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['birth_month']); // filter everything but numbers
        $b_d = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['birth_day']); // filter everything but numbers
    $b_y = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_POST['birth_year']); // filter everything but numbers
    $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $password = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['password']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $pf = preg_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['pf']);
    $sa = preg_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['sa']);
    $ba = preg_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['ba']);
    $ve = preg_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['be']);
    $bu = preg_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['bu']);
    $se = preg_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['se']);
    // Check to see if the user filled all fields with
    // the "Required"(*) symbol next to them in the join form
    // and print out to them what they have forgotten to put in
    if((!$username) || (!$firstname) || (!$surname) || (!$accounttype) || (!$b_m) || (!$b_d) || (!$b_y) || (!$email) || (!$password)){

    $errorMsg = "You did not submit the following required information!<br /><br />";
    if(!$username){
        $errorMsg .= "--- User Name";
    } else if(!$accounttype){ 
       $errorMsg .= "--- Account Type"; 
    } else if(!$b_m){ 
        $errorMsg .= "--- Birth Month";      
    } else if(!$b_d){ 
        $errorMsg .= "--- Birth Day";
    } else if(!$b_y){ 
        $errorMsg .= "--- Birth year";
    } else if(!$firstname){
        $errorMsg .= "--- First Name";
    } else if(!$surname){ 
       $errorMsg .= "--- Surname"; 
    } else if(!$email){ 
       $errorMsg .= "--- Email Address"; 
    } else if(!$password){ 
       $errorMsg .= "--- Password"; 
    }       

    } else {
// Database duplicate Fields Check
$sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM memberstable WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
$sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM memberstable WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
$username_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_username_check);
$email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check); 
if ($username_check > 0){ 
    $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your User Name is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
} else if($email_check > 0){ 
    $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your Email address is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
} else {
    // Add MD5 Hash to the password variable
   $hashedPass = md5($password);

   // Convert Birthday to a DATE field type format(YYYY-MM-DD) out of the month, day, and year supplied 
 $full_birthday = "$b_y-$b_m-$b_d";

    // Add user info into the database table, claim your fields then values 
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO memberstable (username, firstname, surname, accounttype, email, birthday, password) 
    VALUES('$username','$firstname','$surname','$accounttype','$email','$full_birthday','$hashedPass')") or die (mysql_error());
    // Get the inserted ID here to use in the activation email
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    // Create directory(folder) to hold each user files(pics, MP3s, etc.) 
    mkdir("memberFiles/$id", 0755); 
    // Start assembly of Email Member the activation link
    $to = "$email";
    // Change this to your site admin email
    $from = "admin@getscene.com";
    $subject = "Complete your registration";
    //Begin HTML Email Message where you need to change the activation URL inside
    $message = '<html>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    Hi ' . $firstname . ',
    <br /><br />
    You must complete this step to activate your account with us.
    <br /><br />
    Please click here to activate now &gt;&gt;
    <a href="http://www.getscene.com/activation.php?id=' . $id . '">
    ACTIVATE NOW</a>
    <br /><br />
    Your Login Data is as follows: 
    <br /><br />
    E-mail Address: ' . $email . ' <br />
    Password: ' . $password . ' 
    <br /><br /> 
    Thanks! 
    </body>
    </html>';
    // end of message
    $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $to = "$to";
    // Finally send the activation email to the member
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    // Then print a message to the browser for the joiner 
    header( 'Location: http://localhost/urshow/registrationsuccess.php' ) ;
    // Exit so the form and page does not display, just this success message
    } // Close else after database duplicate field value checks
  } // Close else after missing vars check
} //Close if $_POST
?>
```

for the html i have

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Getscene registration</title>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</script>


</head>

<body>
<?php include_once "header_template.php"; ?>
<style type="text/css">
#account_types > div { display: none; }
</style>
<div id="signupwrapper">
    <div id="signupinner">
        <h3 align="left"> GETSCENE REGISTRATION ! </h3>
        <hr />
        <div id="signup" style="border:thin; border-color:#666">
        <h4 align="left">Please Choose One of The Following Account Types</h4>
        <div id="accountswrapper">
            <form id="accountchoice" name="accountchoice" method="post" action="">
                <label for="personalfan">personal/fan</label>   
                <input type="radio" name="pf" id="personalfan" value="radio1" checked="checked" />

                <label for="soloartist">Solo artist</label>   
                <input type="radio" name="sa" id="soloartist" value="radio2" />

                <label for="band">band</label>               
                <input type="radio" name="ba" id="band" value="radio3" />

                <label for="venue">venue</label>   
                <input type="radio" name="ve" id="venue" value="radio4" />

                <label for="business">business</label>   
                <input type="radio" name="bu" id="business" value="radio5" />

                <label for="service">service</label>   
                <input type="radio" name="se" id="service" value="radio6" />
            </form>  

            <hr />
            <div id="account_types">
                <div class="personalfan">
                <table width="400" border="0" align="center">
                <form action="regpersonal.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><?php echo "$errorMsg"; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Username:</div></td>
                    <td><label for="username"></label>
                        <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="30" /></td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="146"><div align="right">First Name:</div></td>
                    <td width="244"><label for="firstname"></label>
                        <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" size="30" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Surname:</div></td>
                    <td><label for="surname"></label>
                    <input name="surname" type="text" id="surname" size="30" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Email Address:</div></td>
                    <td><label for="email"></label>
                    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Password:</div></td>
                    <td><label for="password"></label>
                    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Date Of Birth:</div></td>
                <td>                
                    <select name="birth_day" class="formFields" id="birth_day">
                        <option value='01'>01</option>
                    <option value='02'>02</option>
                    <option value='03'>03</option>
                    <option value='04'>04</option>
                    <option value='05'>05</option>
                    <option value='06'>06</option>
                    <option value='07'>07</option>
                    <option value='08'>08</option>
                    <option value='09'>09</option>
                    <option value='10'>10</option>
                    <option value='11'>11</option>
                    <option value='12'>12</option>
                    <option value='13'>13</option>
                    <option value='14'>14</option>
                    <option value='15'>15</option>
                    <option value='16'>16</option>
                    <option value='17'>17</option>
                    <option value='18'>18</option>
                    <option value='19'>19</option>
                    <option value='20'>20</option>
                    <option value='21'>21</option>
                    <option value='22'>22</option>
                    <option value='23'>23</option>
                    <option value='24'>24</option>
                    <option value='25'>25</option>
                    <option value='26'>26</option>
                    <option value='27'>27</option>
                    <option value='28'>28</option>
                    <option value='29'>29</option>
                    <option value='30'>30</option>
                    <option value='31'>31</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name="birth_month" class="formFields" id="birth_month">
                        <option value='01'>January</option>
                    <option value='02'>February</option>
                    <option value='03'>March</option>
                    <option value='04'>April</option>
                    <option value='05'>May</option>
                    <option value='06'>June</option>
                    <option value='07'>July</option>
                    <option value='08'>August</option>
                    <option value='09'>September</option>
                    <option value='10'>October</option>
                    <option value='11'>November</option>
                    <option value='12'>December</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name="birth_year" class="formFields" id="birth_year">
                        <option value='2012'>2012</option>
                    <option value='2011'>2011</option>
                    <option value='2010'>2010</option>
                    <option value='2009'>2009</option>
                    <option value='2008'>2008</option>
                    <option value='2007'>2007</option>
                    <option value='2006'>2006</option>
                    <option value='2005'>2005</option>
                    <option value='2004'>2004</option>
                    <option value='2003'>2003</option>
                    <option value='2002'>2002</option>
                    <option value='2001'>2001</option>
                    <option value='2000'>2000</option>
                    <option value='1999'>1999</option>
                    <option value='1998'>1998</option>
                    <option value='1997'>1997</option>
                    <option value='1996'>1996</option>
                    <option value='1995'>1995</option>
                    <option value='1994'>1994</option>
                    <option value='1993'>1993</option>
                    <option value='1992'>1992</option>
                    <option value='1991'>1991</option>
                    <option value='1990'>1990</option>
                    <option value='1989'>1989</option>
                    <option value='1988'>1988</option>
                    <option value='1987'>1987</option>
                    <option value='1986'>1986</option>
                    <option value='1985'>1985</option>
                    <option value='1984'>1984</option>
                    <option value='1983'>1983</option>
                    <option value='1982'>1982</option>
                    <option value='1981'>1981</option>
                    <option value='1980'>1980</option>
                    <option value='1979'>1979</option>
                    <option value='1978'>1978</option>
                    <option value='1977'>1977</option>
                    <option value='1976'>1976</option>
                    <option value='1975'>1975</option>
                    <option value='1974'>1974</option>
                    <option value='1973'>1973</option>
                    <option value='1972'>1972</option>
                    <option value='1971'>1971</option>
                    <option value='1970'>1970</option>
                    <option value='1969'>1969</option>
                    <option value='1968'>1968</option>
                    <option value='1967'>1967</option>
                    <option value='1966'>1966</option>
                    <option value='1965'>1965</option>
                    <option value='1964'>1964</option>
                    <option value='1963'>1963</option>
                    <option value='1962'>1962</option>
                    <option value='1961'>1961</option>
                    <option value='1960'>1960</option>
                    <option value='1959'>1959</option>
                    <option value='1958'>1958</option>
                    <option value='1957'>1957</option>
                    <option value='1956'>1956</option>
                    <option value='1955'>1955</option>
                    <option value='1954'>1954</option>
                    <option value='1953'>1953</option>
                    <option value='1952'>1952</option>
                    <option value='1951'>1951</option>
                    <option value='1950'>1950</option>
                    <option value='1949'>1949</option>
                    <option value='1948'>1948</option>
                    <option value='1947'>1947</option>
                    <option value='1946'>1946</option>
                    <option value='1945'>1945</option>
                    <option value='1944'>1944</option>
                    <option value='1943'>1943</option>
                    <option value='1942'>1942</option>
                    <option value='1941'>1941</option>
                    <option value='1940'>1940</option>
                    <option value='1939'>1939</option>
                    <option value='1938'>1938</option>
                    <option value='1937'>1937</option>
                    <option value='1936'>1936</option>
                    <option value='1935'>1935</option>
                    <option value='1934'>1934</option>
                    <option value='1933'>1933</option>
                    <option value='1932'>1932</option>
                    <option value='1931'>1931</option>
                    <option value='1930'>1930</option>
                    <option value='1929'>1929</option>
                    <option value='1928'>1928</option>
                    <option value='1927'>1927</option>
                    <option value='1926'>1926</option>
                    <option value='1925'>1925</option>
                    <option value='1924'>1924</option>
                    <option value='1923'>1923</option>
                    <option value='1922'>1922</option>
                    <option value='1921'>1921</option>
                    <option value='1920'>1920</option>
                    <option value='1919'>1919</option>
                    <option value='1918'>1918</option>
                    <option value='1917'>1917</option>
                    <option value='1916'>1916</option>
                    <option value='1915'>1915</option>
                    <option value='1914'>1914</option>
                    <option value='1913'>1913</option>
                    <option value='1912'>1912</option>
                    <option value='1911'>1911</option>
                    <option value='1910'>1910</option>
                    <option value='1909'>1909</option>
                    <option value='1908'>1908</option>
                    <option value='1907'>1907</option>
                    <option value='1906'>1906</option>
                    <option value='1905'>1905</option>
                    <option value='1904'>1904</option>
                    <option value='1903'>1903</option>
                    <option value='1902'>1902</option>
                    <option value='1901'>1901</option>
                    <option value='1900'>1900</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>
                </form>
                </table></div>
                <div class ="soloartist"></div>
                <div class="band"></div>
                <div class="venue"></div>
                <div class="business"></div>
                <div class="service"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#accountchoice').change(function() {
        var divToShow = $(this).find('input:checked').attr('id');
        $('#account_types > div').each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass(divToShow)) { $(this).show(); }
            else { $(this).hide();}
        });

    });
    $('#accountchoice').trigger('change');

});
</script>

<?php include_once "footer_template.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

ad in mysql my table has a field called accounttype, which as i said uses an enum format this is the row

accounttype     enum('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' one set spare for admin

what would i need for php to get the selected radio button to set account type based on the radios value. i have little to no previous use of radio buttons and have tried a few things but they all fail.

any help here would be a godsend

edited to show all code

Comment: What is your problem? Each "category" should have its own "name" for your radios. So e.g. value=radio1-6 should have a name="radio1..6" and the radios before should have any diffrent name, but not "radio"

Comment: Ok, got your question wrong. Anyway, why you just can't use $_POST['radio'] or $_POST['radio'] == "radio1" ?

Comment: Didn't get it at first with setup you have. Do you mean checked='checked' is hard-coded? Also, did you just omit the end of the form or you really don't have any 'Submit' button for it?

Comment: yes i do have a submit button lol

Comment: So can you give the whole html code and the whole php code?

Comment: im doing my parsing in php which sits on top of the html, i have renamed the name= to unique names and am in the process of setting variables for them, once i have done that is it just a case of using if and else statements?

Comment: You don't need unique names. Group of radio buttons have the same name. If you don't have 'checked' hard-coded, it should be fine. Of course you can use drop-down instead, but it should work.

Comment: ok i have edited the post to show the whole doc

Comment: you know looking it it now i can see an issue myself, i split the form down as i wanted the accounts up top so i could show the fields neeed for each account in a seperate div. so i have 2 forms, one without a submit button which is why i guess no matter what i do the data wont get posted into mysql. should use a drop down instead

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to have one form - you don't have any action associated with the first form - those radio buttons should be within the form that has an action associated (php file). action="" means it's processed by current page - which actually doesn't do any processing.

2) You do keep THE SAME name for all radio buttons.

3) You make that name 'accounttype' as that's what you use to assign a value. (and you don't need any preg_replace there).

4) Run all of your data through mysql_real_escape_string, not just the email.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any library (jquery) you can do this easily.

```
(function($){
    $('#accountchoice').find('input').change(function(){
         if(this.checked){
             if($(this).val() == 'radio1'){
                    // do the needed ajax for radio1 is selected
             }

             // add conditions for all the radio buttons here, or you can use a swicth case too. 
         }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: ok all sorted cheers peeps, went ahead and rebuilt the forms, swapped out radios for dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="radio" name="luckynumber" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="luckynumber" value="2" />
```

In php

```
    print_r($_POST['luckynumber']);
```